# Elementary differentiation enquiry

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Suppose $f(x)=O(g(x))$, and $f,g$ are both infinitely differentiable.. Does it necessarily follow that

$$\frac{d^n}{dx^n} x^{n}\log f(x)\ll \frac{d^n}{dx^n} x^{n}\log g(x)$$ for every positive integer $n$ ?

Comment: Is your $O$ a function, or is it the Big O notation?

Comment: You can edit your question. And to get a good question for MSE, you should add your trials.

Comment: Please explain your notation: as @IV_ asks, is $O$ big $O$ notation? what does $\ll$ mean? IME, it usually means "much less", but it's unclear to me what you mean by it.

Answer (score 1):

No. Your assumption that $\frac{d^n}{dx^n}x^n\ln(f(x))\ll\frac{d^n}{dx^n}x^n\ln(g(x))$ for all unary infinitely differentiable functions $f$ and $g$ is false.

If $O$ is infinitely differentiable:

$$\frac{d^n}{dx^n}x^n\ln(f(x))=\sum_{k=0}^n\left(_k^n\right)(n-k+1)_kx^{n-k}\frac{d^{n-k}}{dx^{n-k}}\ln(O(g(x)))$$

$$\frac{d^n}{dx^n}x^n\ln(g(x))=\sum_{k=0}^n\left(_k^n\right)(n-k+1)_kx^{n-k}\frac{d^{n-k}}{dx^{n-k}}\ln(g(x))$$

The second bracket symbol is the Pochhammer symbol.

Take e.g. functions where $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}\colon \frac{d^n}{dx^n}\ln(O(g(x))\ge \frac{d^n}{dx^n}\ln(g(x))$.

Your assumption is already false if $O$ and $g$ are the same constant function, e.g. $O\colon x\mapsto 1, g\colon x\mapsto 1$:

$$O\colon x\mapsto 1, g\colon x\mapsto 1$$

$$\frac{d^n}{dx^n}x^n\ln(f(x))=\frac{d^n}{dx^n}x^n\ln(g(x))=0$$

$$0\ll 0\text{ is false.}$$

Comment: I don't understand your statement that my assumption is false.